# admin grid action with popup modal

Tags: admin, grid, popup, action

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SelectActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
```

and my class for dropdown action is

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] =
                    [
                    'sendmail' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            self::URL_PATH_MAIL,
                            [
                                'entity_id' => $item['entity_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'id' => 'click-me',
                        'label' => __('Send Mail')
                    ],
                    'view' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_VIEW,
                            [
                                'entity_id' => $item['entity_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('View'),

                    ],
                    'delete' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                            [
                                'entity_id' => $item['entity_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you want to delete a record')
                        ],
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                    ]
                    ];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Grid show dropdown action

[image]

I want to open a popup modal when click on send Mail. 
My try is when I use uicomponent

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/Sendmail</item>
```

Then action column disappear from grid. My Sendmail.js file code is

```
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            title: 'Contact Form',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
        $("#click-me").on('click', function () {
            $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
        });

    }
);
```

For modal html code is in `view/base/web/templates/sendmail.html`

```
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">

//form code

</dive>
```

this sendmail.js code working on frontend site i have test on phtml file it work but is not work with grid. 
Can anyone guide me little how to show popup modal in dropdown action? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the answer?